# NotFoundHttpException and ResourceNotFoundExceptionerror come when run APP in local

Tags: php, silex, bigcommerce

I had use **"hello-world-app-php-silex"** example for Bigcommerce APP.
*https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex*

But get **error** when I run this code:

> (1) NotFoundHttpException in RouterListener.php line 145: No route found
>   for "GET /"
>
> (2) ResourceNotFoundException in UrlMatcher.php line 96:

Can any body help me ?

Comment: take a look at `index.php`, only 2 urls are available `/load` and `/auth/callback`

Comment: I have used this files:
https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex/blob/master/index.php

Comment: Like @MaxP. told you, in that Github example only 2 routes are declared. /load and /auth/callback